# Actualizar valor de moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Estoy trabajando con la librería de manejo de fechas en Javascript Moment.js, y estoy tratando de hacer una especie de calendario, en el que, partiendo de la fecha actual, al pulsar en un botón se retroceda en la fecha, y al pulsar en otro avances.

El problema principal lo tengo en que, si por ejemplo, hoy nos encontramos a 4/07/2017 y reduzco la fecha, efectivamente, va retrocediendo, pero al pulsar después en el de incrementar, se incrementa, pero desde la fecha actual, no desde la fecha a la que he retrocedido anteriormente (y viceversa).

Me imagino que habrá que actualizar el objeto Moment con las respectivas fechas para usarlas como punto de partida, pero no he encontrado forma de hacerlo.

Añado un ejemplo sencillo de codigo para que sea mas entendible (hubiera creado un snippet  pero no consigo que me reconozca la libreria javascript).

Aqui vemos dos botones:

```
<input type="button" value= "-" onclick='fecha(1,0)'/>
<input type="button" value = "+" onclick='fecha(0,1)'/>
```

Ambos botones llamaran a una funcion:

```
function fecha(restar, sumar){  
  var dia = moment();
  if(sumar == 1){
    dia = dia.add(sumar, "days");
    dia = dia.format("DD/MM/YYYY")
    console.log(dia);
  }
  if(restar == 1){
    dia = dia.subtract(restar, "days");
    dia = dia.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    console.log(dia);
  } 
}
```

El problema esta en que cuando quiero sumar o restar a una fecha, parte siempre de la fecha actual, en lugar de desde la fecha que se ha reducido o se ha incrementado.

Espero que esto aclare un poco de claridad sobre mi problema.

Comment: Buenas tardes, perdona la tardanza pero no pude responder antes. Me funciono a la perfección. Tenias razón, el objeto moment se inicializaba cada vez que ejecutaba la función y el código que me has puesto como solución me ha reducido la cantidad de código en gran media. Muchas gracias por la ayuda y el tiempo gastado :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre sale el dia actual porque estas asignando `dia` como `moment()`, lo cual coge la fecha actual.

Has de inicializar el input como la fecha de hoy y luego hacer los calculos cogiendo el valor que tenga el `input`.

Para pasar de `string` a fecha (para sumar o restar 1) has de pasar el valor de el `input` como parametro al metodo `moment` y especificando el formato que deseas

```js
var  inputFecha = document.getElementById("fecha");

inputFecha.value = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY");



function fecha(restar, sumar){  
 
  if(sumar == 1){
    inputFecha.value = moment(inputFecha.value, "DD-MM-YYYY").add(sumar, 'days').format("DD/MM/YYYY");

    console.log(inputFecha.value);
  }if(restar == 1) {
    inputFecha.value = moment(inputFecha.value, "DD-MM-YYYY").subtract(restar, 'days').format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    console.log(inputFecha.value);
  } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value= "-" onclick='fecha(1, 0)'/>
<input type="text" id="fecha"/>
<input type="button" value = "+" onclick='fecha(0, 1)'/>
```